# In typescript the filtering the array is not working

Tags: javascript

```
filtervalue = {
serviceLine:['cca','ga']
}

this.inProgresDetailsData = [{serviceLine:'cca'}, { serviceLine:'cca'}, { serviceLine:'bca'}]
this.hrResourceDetailsdata= this.inProgresDetailsData.filter(item => {
          for (let index = 0; index < filterValue.serviceLine.length; index++) {
            item.serviceLine == filterValue.serviceLine[index]
          }
        });`
```

this.hrResourceDetailsdata is empty on filtering

Comment: `Array.filter` method should return a booleanish value to filter the array. In your case, you are not returning any value so it returns `undefined` which is a falsy value. That's why you get no items.

Comment: What value do you wan to hold in `this.hrResourceDetailsdata`?

Comment: If `filtervalue = {
serviceLine:[]
}`
then it should return the whole array, can anybody help me

Answer (score 2):

The `Array.prototype.filter` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) function expects you to `return` a boolean value that decides whether to keep the current item or not.

Since you are originally not returning any value, you implicitly return `undefined` which when checked against a boolean resolves to `false`, hence, all of your array items are discarded one by one, leaving none remaining.

You want to return the boolean to make this work:

```js
this.hrResourceDetailsdata = this.inProgresDetailsData.filter(item => {
  for (let index = 0; index < filterValue.serviceLine.length; index++) {
    if (item.serviceLine == filterValue.serviceLine[index]) {
      return true; // return true if found, otherwise continue
    }
  }
  return false; // filter is never found in loop, fall back to false
});
```

Also, you can use `Array.prototype.includes` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)) to simplify your check, the following code does the exact same thing:

```
this.hrResourceDetailsdata = this.inProgresDetailsData.filter(item => {
  // return true if `item.serviceLine` is inside `filterValue.serviceLine`
  return filterValue.serviceLine.includes(item.serviceLine);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) out of `filterValue.serviceLine` and filter out the items that are present in the set.

```js
const 
  filterValue = { serviceLine: ["cca", "ga"] },
  inProgressDetailsData = [
    { serviceLine: "cca" },
    { serviceLine: "cca" },
    { serviceLine: "bca" },
  ],
  filterSet = new Set(filterValue.serviceLine),
  hrResourceDetailsdata = inProgressDetailsData.filter(({ serviceLine }) =>
    filterSet.has(serviceLine)
  );

console.log(hrResourceDetailsdata);
```

If you want to apply multiple filters, then:

- Create an object containing filters in form of `Set`s.
- Filter items where all the filters are applicable using [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const 
  filterValue = {
    serviceLine: ["cca", "ga"],
    urgency: ["medium", "high"],
  },
  filterSet = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(filterValue).map(([k, v]) => [k, new Set(v)])
  ),
  inProgressDetailsData = [
    { id: 1, urgency: "low", serviceLine: "cca" },
    { id: 2, urgency: "medium", serviceLine: "cca" },
    { id: 3, urgency: "low", serviceLine: "bca" },
    { id: 4, urgency: "high", serviceLine: "ga" },
    { id: 5, urgency: "low", serviceLine: "abc" },
  ],
  hrResourceDetailsdata = inProgressDetailsData.filter((data) =>
    Object.entries(filterSet).every(([k, v]) => v.has(data[k]))
  );

console.log(hrResourceDetailsdata);
```

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(iterable?: Iterable<unknown> | null | undefined): Set<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<unknown> | null | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(values?: readonly any[] | null | undefined): Set<any>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly any[] | null | undefined'.ts(2769)

Comment: `filterSet = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(filterValue).map(([k, v]) => [k, new Set(v)])
  )`
Above error for ' Set(v)' on hovering on 'v'

Comment: @shivakuamaragowda Can you paste your code in TypeScript playground and share the link. It's really hard to derive any meaning like this.

Comment: I have used the same code in angular 12. I am getting errors. I am unaware of TypeScript playground.

Comment: `    const filterSet = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(filterValue).map(([k, v]) => [k, new Set(v)])
      )
      this.hrResourceDetailsdata = this.inProgresDetailsData.filter((data) =>
      Object.entries(filterSet).every(([k, v]) => v.has(data[k]))
    );`

Answer (score -1):

Code

```js
filtervalue = {
    serviceLine:['cca','ga']
};

this.inProgresDetailsData = [
    { serviceLine:'cca'}, 
    { serviceLine:'cca'}, 
    { serviceLine:'bca'}
];
this.hrResourceDetailsdata = this.inProgresDetailsData.filter(item => { 
    return filtervalue.serviceLine.includes(item.serviceLine)
});

console.log(this.hrResourceDetailsdata)
```

Comment: if ` filterValue = {
    serviceLine: [""],
    urgency: ["medium", "high"],
  },`
any solution for this case please?

Comment: can you please share your expected output? and input values for filterValue &  this.inProgresDetailsData?